# Get text on items and sub-items contextmenustrip

Tags: c#, toolstrip, contextmenustrip

I have a contextmenustrip in the toolStripDropDownButton with the following items and sub-items:

```
private void addItem()
{
    toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDown = this.contextMenuStrip1;
    contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("item A");
    contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("item B");
    contextMenuStrip1.Items.Add("item C");
    addSubItem();
}

private void addSubItem()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < contextMenuStrip1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        (contextMenuStrip1.Items[i] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("SubItem 1");
        (contextMenuStrip1.Items[i] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("SubItem 2");
        (contextMenuStrip1.Items[i] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems.Add("SubItem 3");
    }
}
```

I want to ask, how do I get text on items and sub-items if I just click on any sub-item. for example I click on Subitem 2 in item C, then the output is `item C and Subitem 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the Click event for the sub items and use the OwnerItem property to get the parent menu for that sub item.

Inside the addSubItem()

```
 foreach (ToolStripMenuItem item in (contextMenuStrip1.Items[i] as ToolStripMenuItem).DropDownItems)
                {
                    item.Click += Item_Click;
                }
```

and the Click event is

```
private void Item_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string parentMenuText = (sender as ToolStripMenuItem).OwnerItem.Text;
        string subItemText = (sender as ToolStripMenuItem).Text;
    }
```